# Installing DevExpress Data Grid in a Turborepo monorepo application that runs on NUXT3

Tags: nuxt.js, devexpress, nuxtjs3, monorepo, turborepo

I have a Turborepo monorepo that holds 3 applications under the apps/ directory and some shared packages under packages/shared.

My monorepo structure is like this

```
-apps
--app1
--app2
--app3
-packages
--shared
```

All of my 3 apps are NUXT3 apps.

I want to install devextreme-vue and use the DxDataGrid component in my apps in order to create tables.

I have installed the library by doing `npm install devextreme@23.1 devextreme-vue@23.1 --save --save-exact` while being in packages/shared.
The library is installed fine and I can find the relevant directories in node_modules.

In my `apps/app1/pages/admin/index.vue` I am trying to make use of the `DxDataGrid` like

```
<template>
  <DxDataGrid :data-source="subscribers" :columns="columns" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import useAdmin from "../../../../packages/shared/composables/useAdmin";
import DxDataGrid from "../../../../node_modules/devextreme-vue";

export default defineComponent({
  async setup() {
    definePageMeta({
      middleware: ["auth"],
    });

    const user = await useUser().get();

    const subscribers = await useAdmin().getSubscribers();
    const columns = ["name", "kind"];

    return { user, subscribers, columns };
  },
});
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

This doesn't work though and I am getting the following warning in console

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: DxDataGrid
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. 
  at <Index onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <RouteProvider key="/admin" vnode= 
  at <RouterView name=undefined route=undefined > 
  at <NuxtPage> 
  at <DashLayout> 
  at <App key=3 > 
  at <NuxtRoot>
```

Am I missing something? Should I register the library somehow else?